# Getting "Could not load type" error after upgrading to latest Crystal Reports Runtime version 13.0.21.2533

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

We have a working application, ASP.NET Web forms that uses the Crystal Reports runtime and displays reports in an embedded Print Preview window.  It is deployed on a Windows 2012 server and works with CR Runtime v13.0.18 and below.

Today we installed the latest Crystal Reports runtime version 13.0.21.2533 (downloaded from http://www.crystalreports.com/crvs/confirm/) and the Print Preview windows now raises this error:

Parser Error 
 Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MyApp.printPreview1'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"
>   CodeBehind="printPreview.ascx.vb" Inherits="MyApp.printPreview1"
>   EnableViewState="true" %>  Line 2:  <%@ Register
>   Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web"
>   TagPrefix="CR" %>  Line 3:       Source File: 
>   /MyApp/printPreview.ascx    Line:  1

Rolling back to any version prior to v..21 seems to work OK but these older releases have disappeared from SAP/Crystal web site forcing us to use runtime v..21.

This is a breaking change that leaves all reporting in our application non-operational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing the Crystal web site about this update here:

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads

Specifically:

> Below items should be highlight for SP21:
> ...
>
> 4. As most of CR/RAS .NET Assemblies are now re-versioned from 13.0.2000.0 to 13.0.3500.0, user MUST remove all old CR assemblies from Reference list and add the new version of CR assemblies, then
>    rebuild the application.
>    a.    For those customer/user who do not
>    wanted to rebuilt their application, there’s workaround to use
>    `<dependentAssembly>` in app.config/web.config, please see attachment.

I appears you must a) change your version references to 13.0.3500.0 in web.config and b) rebuild your application in Visual Studio.

This isn't really a practical option for us as we have several in-place installs that will instantly break and a rebuild isn't straightforward with an in-production, live application.

Instead we chose to use the dependentAssembly approach listed in point "4.a" above.  Basically all we did was edit the web.config add this block:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Shared" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Web" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonControls" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CubeDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ObjectFactory" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Prompting" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

directly above the closing `</configuration>` tag, saved, and  and the Print Preview window started working.

This has been a viable workaround until we roll out a new release with the newer Crystal Runtime references built into the binaries.